# Python array error occures 1-3 times in 100 cases

Tags: python, arrays

I have a complete ( partially working) program of a problem, where function should pick "n" random items from one array and put them to another array and if there are same elements in array n.1 it can't put more than one of those elements in array n.2

Code:

```
import random

def pick(n, array):
    array2 = []
    for i in range(len(array)):
        if len(array2) == n:
            break
        random_index = 0
        random_index= random.randint(0,len(array)-1)
        element = array[random_index]
        if element not in array2:
            array2.append(element)
    return array2
```

For example take an array a:

```
a=['matt', 'john', 'peter', 'john', 'joseph', 'adam', 'steven', 'paul']
```

and run it, for example 100 times:

```
for i in range(100):
    pick(4,a)
```

You will notice, that some arrays consist of only 3 elements and they all should be 4! So my question is why is that ?

Comment: Why do you use `for i in range(len(array))`? That puts an upper bound on the number of attempts you'll use to get a unique random number.

Comment: @Mark Ransom Thank you ! I thought I do not need to run it more than the length of the array n.1. I already changed it to while `len(array) != n` and it is working. Stupid mistake, but thank you !

Comment: If you make a copy of the input array, chose the element from the copy and then remove the chosen element from the copy; then you will only need to only have to run the loop `n` times at most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change

```
for i in range(len(array))
## to
while len(array2) < n:
## or
while True:  ## infinite loop until the break statement is executed
```

Your program will choose a random element len(array) times [and it is not an array, but a list], and it does not depend on the length of arrary2.  So there could be only 1 or 2 elements depending on how many times a duplicate was picked.  Also, change

```
    if len(array2) == n:
        break
    ## to
    if len(array2) == n:
        return array2
```

to avoid make it clearer what is happening.

Comment: Thank you, yes Mark Ramson wrote it too. I already changed it to: `while len(array) != n`